# Focus NSAlert accessory item

Tags: objective-c, dialog, prompt, nstextfield, nsalert

I have an NSAlert item that uses an NSTextField as an accessory item to provide an prompt-like dialog box. The only problem that I have is that when the alert is ran the text field is not focused. I tried looking for a way to change NSAlert's first responder but found nothing. Is there a way to easy focus an accessory item in NSAlert?

Answer (score 28):

It seems like you should be able to do something like:

```
[[alert window] setInitialFirstResponder: myAccessoryView];
```

before the alert is shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSWindow makeFirstResponder:] but must make sure to call this after the alert is displayed.